# Alfresco share search not working

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

[image]Whenever I search something in alfresco share search , I am getting No result found. I tried even the exact file name. But the advanced search is able to find.
What is the problem?
Can I make the default search as advanced search?

Comment: Too less info. In the last weeks you've asked a lot of questions which some of you could find out on your own. I suggest you take an Alfresco training before you should continue. This Stack is for development/technical questions and not for your daily functional questions.

Comment: @TahirMalik I added the image now. Sorry, but I search before asking questions but the alfresco forum is not active as much and almost all question in alfresco forum were left  unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to click on the tab Repository instead of All Sites